# Describing multilinear maps as linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ be given.  Let $T^k(V)$ denote the vector space of multilinear maps $V^k\to\mathbb C$.

My original question was going to be as follows: Does there exist a vector space $W$ for which $T^k(V)$ is isomorphic to the vector space $\mathrm{End}(W)$ of linear operators on $W$?

But it occured to me that since any two finite-dimensional, complex vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, and since
\begin{align}
\dim T^k(V) = (\dim V)^k, \qquad \dim \mathrm{End}(W) = (\dim W)^2
\end{align}
The question boils down to whether there exists a vector space $W$ for which
\begin{align}
  (\dim V)^k = (\dim W)^2
\end{align}
If I haven't made an error thus far, then it's immediate that if, for example, $\dim V = 2$ and $k = 1$, then no such $W$ exists.  In contrast one is guaranteed that $W$ exists at least whenever $\dim V$ is a perfect square.

Am I missing something?

Moreover, for those $T^k(V)$ for which such a $W$ does exist, is there some natural construction that exhibits the isomorphism in an intuitive way?  What exactly would a vector space of linear operators that mimicks a vector space of multilinear operators "look like?"  In other words, is there some isomorphism in this context that is natural in some sense?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. If you're only looking for isomorphisms (opposed to some type of natural ones) you're basically asking if $n\choose k$ is always a square--it isn't.

Comment: At first glance, it seems to me that the question is equivalent to the question "Are all tensor products decomposable?" and that is certainly not true in general.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for the confirmation.  When you write $\binom{n}{k}$, do you mean $n^k$ since $\dim T^k(V) = n^k$ when $\dim V = n$?  Otherwise, would you mind explaining the appearance of the binomial coefficient?